# How can I add validate dimension in pixels with rules laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.3, rules, laravel-validation

I use laravel 5.3

My validate rules laravel like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class StoreProfileCreateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    ..
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'banner'=> 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:7024'
        ];
    }
}
```

I want to add validate dimensions in pixels. So if user not upload banner with dimension 1170 x 300 pixels there exist message like this :

```
Please upload an image with 1170 x 300 pixels dimension
```

How can I add the validate on the rules?

Comment: Again ... https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#available-validation-rules  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation . "Dimensions" section.

You just will need to use similar to this.

'avatar' => 'dimensions:min_width=100,min_height=200'